# Create a single workflow template for use with different libraries (different task participants)

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, document-library, approval-process

Copying and Modifying the Globally reusable 2010 Approval - SharePoint 2010 Workflow, I was able to create a new template workflow.

I removed the "Approvers" and the "expand group" options from the Initiation Form Parameters and instead used a a hard coded value for the Task Process Participants. Here is an example used for a single Document Library:

[image]

The problem here is that I have to create a template for many different libraries, the only difference is is the task process participants. Is there a better way to create a single template and then set the participants parameter at workflow creation? I do not want users to be able to edit the participants field when they start the workflow, I do want admins to be able to specify when the workflow is setup. Can I implement this without creating a new workflow template for each different approval process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution (may or may not work in all cases) was to modify the initiation form parameters of the workflow, In SharePoint Designer:

1. Find the desired workflow
2. Click Initiation Form Parameters
3. If you want the form parameters to not be changeable during the workflow initiation, you need to make sure the parameter is specified during association only. Modify the fields that you want to be static to be Association only.

[image]